# AWS MWAA remote logging not visible on Airflow UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, airflow-2.x, mwaa

AWS MWAA is configured for remote logging to a given S3 path.

While running tasks(preferably long and time-consuming) in any DAG, we can not see logs either on Airflow UI or the S3 path.

Whenever a task ends(success or failure), we are able to see logs at both places.

Is there any way to see logs while running tasks in case of remote logging?